# Exception while compiling: wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0

Tags: java, exception, jxl

I am working an application with JXL API and when i tried compiling using eclipse IDE, it's working fine and the same is not compiling when i am trying to compile in Command prompt and showing the below exception..

```
Extract.java:6: cannot access jxl.read.biff.BiffException bad class file: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_01\jre\lib\ext\jxl.jar(jxl/read/biff/BiffException.class)
class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpa
th.
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
                     ^
1 error
```

EDIT:

I am able to executing using JDK 1.6. Since JDK 1.6 must also be compatible with lower versions, why doesn't it support the class files which were compiled in JDK 1.5.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your answers and comments, i've recoverd the problem followed oscar reyes sugesstions.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The library you're using was compiled with Java 6

Your compiler is Java 5 that's why it doesn't understand that format.

To fix it you have to get a 1.5 version of the library or upgrade your compiler to 1.6 I suggest the later.

Comment: Oh, that's no mystery - eclipse ships with it's own compiler so you don't even need a jdk. And that compiler is Java6 compliant :)

Answer (score 3):

Per http://www.jnode.org/node/2140...

> Submitted by Stephen Crawley on Fri, 11/30/2007 - 07:15.
>
> I suspect that you are mixing code compiled with different versions of Java. Class file version 50.0 is used by Java 6.0, and 49.0 is used by Java 5.0.
>
> Try doing a "build clean" to get rid of all existing class files, followed by a regular build.
>
> JNode is being developed using Java 6.0 only. Last time I tried, it didn't build using Java 5.0 (aka 1.5). (It is a problem with the program that builds the JNode boot image.)

Try changing the builder in Eclipse.  If you're using 3.4, it's *Project - Properties - Java Compiler - Enable Project Specific Settings - Compiler Compliance Level = 1.6*.  You'll prolly also need to have JRE 1.6 installed, as well.

Comment: Using `mvn clean`, helped me to find out the `mvn.bat` file, which in my case, it was setting its own version of `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

Check you class path in eclipse and make sure that its the same class path your compiling to in the command prompt, also check your library imports

Comment: Yeah i have checked out everything, everything is right. But even i am getting the exception.

Answer (score 1):

It means that, you have compiled that class with Java 6 and trying to execute with Java 5.

**Solution :**

**If your using ant**, execute below steps on the project root directory

1. ant clean
2. ant deploy

**If your using eclipse**, just 
clean the workspace(remove the class files which were compiled with Java6) 
and build again

Answer (score 0):

this could be that in you IDE you point to latest version of JDK but when you build your program outside the IDE(maybe with maven) your java_home is the older version to the one on your IDE.