# different version of java and compiled classes jar

Tags: java

i have java 2 SDK standard edition `ve 1.4.2-06` and i compile a java program that use the classes in a jar called `Visad` after extracting the contents of the jar I have a folder called Visad also contains subfolders of classes. I compile my program and I always receive this error message

```
cannot access visad.java3d.DisplayImplJ3D bad class file .\visad\java3d\DisplayImplJ3D.class 
class file has wrong version 50.0 should be 48.0 
please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath
```

i read that maybe the problem is the version of my java which is different from the compiled classesin jar , i d'ont know what to do

thanks

Comment: Why you have 2 JDKs? What versions are they? Which JDK you use to compile and which JRE to run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception while compiling: wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766216/exception-while-compiling-wrong-version-50-0-should-be-49-0)

Comment: If you are going to use a historical version of of Java like 1.4, 5.0 or 6, you should at least have the latest update of that JDK for that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cannot access visad.java3d.DisplayImplJ3D bad class file .\visad\java3d\DisplayImplJ3D.class 
class file has wrong version 50.0 should be 48.0
```

The part of the error message "class file has wrong version 50.0" tells that the class file DisplayImplJ3D.class was created using a JDK 1.6 and your are using a javac compiler from JDK 1.4 "should be 48.0".

- if you must stick on JDK 1.4 you need a Visad.jar which was compiled with Java 1.4
- if there is no constraint to stick on JDK 1.4 you should update at least to JDK 1.6 and compile your source

**edit** your could also download the Visad source [Visad homepage](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~billh/visad.html#get) and compile it with your JDK

HOWTO build VisAD with JDK 1.4

- download the VisAD source and extract it to your prefered destination
- download and install Java 3D API for JDK 1.4 from [Java 3D API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html), during the installation check where the *.jar file will be installed
- `cd` into the VisAD source directory
- run `ant build jar`
- if the build fails with `error: package javax.media.j3d does not exist` then you must copy the necessary Jar files manually from the installation directory (you had to remember during the installation)
- copy the files j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar and vecmath.jar to your VisAD source directory
- amend the `build.xml`, add the bold part

  <javac srcdir="." memoryMaximumSize="512M" fork="true" debug="on" **classpath=".;j3dcore.jar;j3dutils.jar;vecmath.jar"** />
- run `ant build jar`
- if the build was successful there should be a visad.jar in the VisAD source directory

Comment: i installed java 2 SDK SE ve 1.4.2-06 bcause i need  it to install Java3d-1_3_1-windowsi586-opengel.

Comment: when i get visad_src and i unpack it i have subfolders and i don't know how i can compile classes Inside subfolders

Comment: You should rather use the latest version of Java 3D which is a lot less painful to install (with a more recent JDK) and still compatible with the old versions as the public API remains unchanged: http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using java compiler of version 1.4 with classes that have been compiled for 1.5 or 1.6

You should change your version of java to a newer one... You know that we are running java 8 now?

You should download and install java SE 8
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html